# How to show previous dates till today and next dates for some years on polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How to show previous dates till today and next dates for some years on polymer?
I tried the below script but it was not working.
I am getting only yesterday's and tomorrow's dates on console on repeat. I want the day before then the one before and so on. Also I must not go behind my present day.

```
<header>
  <iron-icon class="icon" icon="chevron-left" on-tap="previousDay" suffix></iron-icon>
  <iron-icon class="icon" icon="chevron-right" on-tap="nextDay" suffix></iron-icon>
</header>
<br/><br/>       



nextDay: function() {
  var currentDay = new Date(); 
  currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() + 1);
  console.log(currentDay);
},

previousDay: function () {
  var currentDay = new Date();
  currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() - 1);
  console.log(currentDay);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be:

```
nextDays: function() {
    var currentDay = new Date();
    var nextDays = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date();
        newDate.setDate(currentDay.getDate() + i);
        nextDays.push(newDate);
    }

    // nextDays will contain the 30 next days
}

previousDays: function() {
    var currentDay = new Date();
    var previousDays = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date();
        newDate.setDate(currentDay.getDate() - i);
        previousDays.push(newDate);
    }

    // previousDays will contain the 30 last days
}
```

You can simply change the number of days you want (30 in this example) and do what you want with the arrays `nextDays` and `previousDays`.

What you can add is for example cache these days so that you don't have to generate them everytime (especially if its for the same day).

Comment: The loop can be one statement using `previousDays.push(new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1)))` while the loop runs. ;-)

Comment: Indeed it can be reduced to that, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using private variables.

```js
var date = (() => {
  var currentDay = new Date();
  
  function previousDay() {
    currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() - 1);
    return currentDay;
  }
  
  function nextDay() {
    currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() + 1);
    return currentDay;
  }
  
  return { previousDay, nextDay };
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(date.previousDay())">Previous day</button>
<button onclick="console.log(date.nextDay())">Next day</button>
```

---

You can even shorten it, both can use the same function:

```js
var date = (() => {
  var currentDay = new Date(),
    previousDay = () => goToDay(-1),
    nextDay = () => goToDay(1);
    
  function goToDay(n) {
    currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() + n);
    return currentDay;
  }
  
  return { previousDay, nextDay };
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(date.previousDay())">Previous day</button>
<button onclick="console.log(date.nextDay())">Next day</button>
```